# get_the_post_thumbnail() doesn't taking style attribute

Tags: attachments, post-thumbnails

This seems to be an easy one but its giving me quite a hard time. [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) suppose to take attribute as an array. Well, everything working right but when i pass style attr its doesn't work.

```
$attr = array(
                                'title' => get_the_title(),
                                'alt' => get_the_title(),
                                'style' => 'float:left'
                            );

$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large-thumb', $attr);
```

The title and the alt attribute is set up nicely though but style attribute is missing in images.

FYI: I am showing the thumbnail in rss feed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_the_post_thumbnail` attribute array doesn't know `STYLE` , the fields that are available for you to use are:

- `src`
- `class`
- `alt`
- `title`

so just use the class and define you class to it:

```
$attr = array(
                                'title' => get_the_title(),
                                'alt' => get_the_title(),
                                'class' => 'rss_thumb'
                            );
$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'large-thumb', $attr);
```

and then define the style in the class:

```
<style>
.rss_thumb{float:left}
</style>
```

### **Update:**

My bad rss feed can really be styled like HTML since its not HTML. so to over come this problem you need to have your image inside the content tag and give it an align="left" which should work in most rss readers.

so what you really want is to add a content_filter:

```
add_filter('the_content','add_rss_thumb');

function add_rss_thumb($content){
    if (!is_feed()){
        return $content;
    }

    //now that we know is a feed we add the image to the content:
    global $post;
    if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        $thumbnail_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id );
        /*
            $thumbnail_attributes is an array containing: 
            [0] => url
            [1] => width
            [2] => height 
        */

        return '<img src="'.thumbnail_attributes[0].'" title="'.the_title_attribute('','',0).'" alt="'.the_title_attribute('','',0).'" align="left">'.$content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: It seems. Wordpress feed does not echo any style attribute directly in html element.

Comment: Note also, for the *title* attribute, you should be using `get_the_title_attribute()`.

Comment: How do i add styles in my rss feed?

Comment: i updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on a good and more global solution for this on Isabel Castillo's blog, by using `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter:

```
function isa_add_img_title( $attr, $attachment = null ) {
    $attr['title'] = trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) );
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','isa_add_img_title', 10, 2 );
```

This way, you could add other attributes as well (e.g. `data-caption`)

Original code on http://isabelcastillo.com/add-title-attribute-wordpress-image-thumbnail